Dotnet 8 saying not installed (but it is) on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with VS2022 Console App
I have an RPi 3B+ with Dotnet 8 installed with this script from Pete Codes here.
The actual script is here...
My dev environment is Visual Studio 2022, then SSH into headless RPi (OS 64 bit Lite installed) to download/run the app.
After my initial setup, when I go to run the console app, I get this error...
Here is my RPi dotnet version...
Here is my Visual Studio 2022 dotnet version...
My question is: why the error?

Questions should be as self contained as possible. Don't make us click links when it's really not necessary. Also post only images where you absolutely need to. None of the above couldn't have been copy&paste'd as text.

You need to install the runtime version of Core for linux.  See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

The .NET SDK is used for development. However, to run the .NET application, you must install the runtime version of the framework.
PS: This is not necessary if running in a container.
See dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download.
